# Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, web-services, ejb

im having a challenge posting data from my j2se client which connects to an EJB module and a webservice, i have created a web service client on the client side to communicate with the web service in the ejb module.

Answer (score 0):

Check the System Firewall's settings and well as Browser settings, if any of the settings is actually blocking the network connection. Also check, if any Antivirus software is having these kind of settings.